# Cannot add Calendar Resource to My Calendars

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have a G Suite Meeting Room and I want to manage its calendar. I'm following the instructions on this page to add a Calendar Resource to "My Calendars", however the section **My Calendars** (capital C) and referenced "+" button in Step 2 below is not present.

> **Note:** This question is specifically to add the calendar to "My calendars" so it can be managed, not to "Other calendars" where it cannot be managed or edited.

What am I missing to complete these instructions?

Here's the instructions:

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/60766

I have the following pre-requisites:

- "administrator account with Calendar and Super Admin privileges"
- "a calendar resource (such as a meeting room) for your organization" - resource with "Calendar-based room release" set to "On" and "Type" set to "Conference Room"

> [image: Instructions]

Here's the screenshot from my user with the required "administrator account with Calendar and Super Admin privileges". There's no **My Calendars** (capital C) or "+" as specified in Step 2 above, but **My calendars** (lowercase C) does exist without a "+".

Here are the steps:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> however the section My Calendars (capital C) and referenced "+" button in Step 2 below is not present.

Click the "+" button on the **Other calendars section**, then follow the rest of the instructions.

---

If you followed the instructions of the help article (considering the above suggestion) and you still doesn't get the result you are looking for, then submit a support ticket to G Suite Admin Support.

Comment: Clicking the "+" button on the Other calendars section won't achieve the desired result as that will add the calendar to the "Other calendars" list so it cannot be managed. I've done this as well and it does show up under "Other calendars". The Google page has the following note: "Note: Users can add the resource to their Other calendars list, where they can view the resource but not edit or manage it."

Comment: That isn't correct if you have permission to manage the calendar. The last week I did this with 6 calendars and all of them are shown on My Calendars.

Comment: I mentioned the pre-requisites I have in my question: (a) user with Calendar and Super Admin privileges and (b) calendar resource. Is anything else needed?

Comment: @Grokify I edited my answer. Tl;Dr: Submit a support ticket to G Suite Support.